# Изменение траектории поворота и вращения объекта в Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Есть код, который крутит объект в заданную сторону, но мне нужно чтобы объект крутился в одну сторону, а по нажатию на левую клавишу мышки объект крутился в другую сторону.

Скрипт:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RotateGun : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] public float speed = 0; // скорость

    void Update()
    {
        transform.Rotate(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0); // вращение object
    }
}
```

Comment: умнажай скорость на -1 по нажатию кнопки

Comment: А причём тут [game-maker]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButton.html

Чтобы обратно, надо умножить на -1.

```
void Update()
{
    float direction = Input.GetMouseButton(0) ? -1f : 1f;
    transform.Rotate(direction * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f);
}
```

> Если возможно, подскажите как сделать так, чтобы сторона поворота объекта менялась без зажатия, то-есть просто по клику.

Документацию то когда читать начнете?
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html

```
private float direction = 1f;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        direction = -direction;
    transform.Rotate(direction * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f);
}
```

Comment: Благодарю вас! Если возможно, подскажите как сделать так, чтобы сторона поворота объекта менялась без зажатия, то-есть просто по клику. Еще раз благодарю!

Comment: @Mr.Bait показал.